# Where would a senior PHP developer locate the method getActiveEntries()?

Tags: php, oop

### Separation of Concerns or Single Responsibility Principle

The majority of the questions in the dropdown list of questions that "may already have your answer" only explain "theory" and are not concrete examples that answer my simple question.

### What I'm trying to accomplish

I have a class named GuestbookEntry that maps to the properties that are in the database table named "guestbook". Very simple!

Originally, I had a static method named getActiveEntries() that retrieved an array of all GuestbookEntry objects that had entries in the database. Then while learning how to properly design php classes, I learned two things:

1. Static methods are not desirable.
2. Separation of Concerns

### My question:

Dealing with Separation of Concerns, if the GuestbookEntry class should only be responsible for managing single guestbook entries then where should this getActiveEntries() method go? I want to learn the absolute proper way to do this.

Comment: This is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: For anyone looking to learn what exactly Database Access Objects (DAO) are, here is a great article, although it is a little old: It will help you understand EXACTLY what they are: http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-patterns-part-ii/

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are actually two items in the question:

1. As @duskwuff points out, there is nothing wrong with static methods per-se; if you know their caveats (e.g. "[Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)") and limitations, they are just another tool to work with. However, the way you model the interaction with the DB does have an impact on separation of concerns and, for example, unit testing.
2. For different reasons there is no "absolute proper way" of doing persistence. One of the reasons is that each way of tackling it has different tradeoffs; which one is better for you project is hard to tell. The other important reason is that languages evolve, so a new language feature can improve the way frameworks handle things. So, instead of looking for the perfect way of doing it you may want to consider different ways of approaching OO persistence assuming that you want so use a relational database:

   - Use the [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern. What you have done so far looks like is in the Active Record style, so you may find it natural. The active record has the advantage of being simple to grasp, but tends to be tightly coupled with the DB (of course this depends on the implementation). This is bad from the separation of concerns view and may complicate testing.
   - Use an ORM (like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/)). In this case most of the hard work is done by the framework (BD mapping, foreign keys, cascade deletes, some standard queries, etc.), but you must adapt to the framework rules (e.g. I recall having a lot of problems with the way Doctrine 1 handled hierarchies in a project. AFAIK this things are solved in Doctrine 2).
   - Roll your own framework to suite your project needs and your programming style. This is clearly a time consuming task, but you learn a lot.

As a general rule of thumb I try to keep my domain models as independent as possible from things like DB, mainly because of unit tests. Unit tests should be running all the time while you are programming and thus they should run fast (I always keep a terminal open while I program and I'm constantly switching to it to run the whole suite after applying changes). If you have to interact with the DB then your tests will become slow (any mid-sized system will have 100 or 200 test methods, so the methods should run in the order of milliseconds to be useful).

Finally, there are different techniques to cope with objects that communicate with DBs (e.g. mock objects), but a good advise is to always have a layer between your domain model and the DB. This will make your model more flexible to changes and easier to test.

EDIT: I forgot to mention the [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) approach, also stated in @MikeSW answer.

HTH

Comment: Ok wow! Thanks for the detailed answer. Now I am trying to figure out which method would be best for someone that wants to learn the best route to become a senior php developer. I basically am trying to learn only those things that I will use from here on out. For instance, if I use active records, I will use it once, and then move on to something that allows for less coupling. So I want to start out with the option that allows for the lowest coupling. Of those that you mentioned, which would you recommend for lowest coupling and highest cohesion?

Comment: I don't recommend Active Record pattern, not for 'real' applications anyway. It's a quick'n'dirty way of doing things and it breaks the SoC principle.

Comment: You are welcome @darga! I learned the hard way and found it really instructive: first I did some manual mapping and reached the point where I couldn't scale anymore. Then I used active record style and then ORMs. I also used OODBs (in Smalltalk, I don't know if there is a OODB for PHP). Of course this was in a long timespan and different projects (some commercials, some in research and some in the academy). My general recommendation is to stick to what you find natural until you see that it doesn't scale or fit your needs anymore. Then you will "feel" the need to switch and you will know the

Comment: weak points of the approach that you were using, so you will know what key points to search in your new persistence schema. I know this path is not optimal, but I really think that there is no silver bullet here.

Comment: Gotcha! So a simple Data Access Object for each of the value objects? Would you suggest that to be the way to go for now?

Comment: I would like to learn doctrine, but I'm thinking that it might be too much of a learning curve for right now when I am trying to learn other important things like the proper way to design the classes.

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing what kind of project you are in (expected size, performance requirements, cost, time, etc). DAO or ActiveRecord sound like good candidates to start, but again, its hard to tell without the proper information. No matter what approach you take just try to keep your domain as separated as possible from the DB so that you can easily mock it and run your tests in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Stop second-guessing yourself. A static method `getActiveEntries()` is a perfectly reasonable way to solve this problem.

The "enterprisey" solution that you're looking for would probably involve something along the lines of creating a GuestbookEntryFactory object, configuring it to fetch active entries, and executing it. This is silly. Static methods are a tool, and this is an entirely appropriate job for them.

Comment: Right, I understand that it is perfectly reasonable. I'm just trying to learn how to do it the way that developers do so that they can write unit tests for it. Don't get me wrong, I haven't learned unit testing yet. But I am trying to take the steps to learn so when I get there, everything will be ready, with dependency injection and no unnecessary statics.

Answer (score 0):

GetActiveEntries should be a method of a repository/DAO which will return an array of GuestBookEntry. That repository of course can implement an interface so here you have easy testing.

I disagree in using a static method for this, as it's clearly a persistence access issue. The GuestBookEntry should care only about the 'business' functionality and never about db. That's why it's useful to use a repository, that object will bridge the business layer to the db layer.

**Edit** My php's rusty but you get the idea.

```
public interface IRetrieveEntries
{
    function GetActiveEntries();
}

public class EntriesRepository implements IRetrieveEntries
{
    private $_db;
    function __constructor($db)
    {
       $this->_db=$db;
     }

    function GetActiveEntries()
    {
      /* use $db to retreive the actual entries
       You can use an ORM, PDO whatever you want 
         */
      //return entries;
    }

  }
```

You'll pass the interface around everywhere you need to access the functionality i.e you don't couple the code to the actual repository. You will use it for unit testing as well. The point is that you encapsulate the real data access in the GetActiveEntries method, the rest of the app won't know about the database.

About repository pattern you can read [some tutorials](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/02/22/The-Repository-Pattern-Explained.aspx) I've wrote (ignore the C# used, the concepts are valid in any language)

Comment: I have never used a repository/DAO before. Can you provide a simple example utilizing getActiveEntries()?

Comment: So when you mention repository, are you actually referring to the same thing as DAO but with the name repository?

Comment: No. Repository is a high level concept which abstracts the persistence layer. DAO is just an object used to access data directly (Active Record is implemented as a DAO for example).  A repository might use a DAO (among other ways) to actually work with the database.

Comment: Oh boy Mike! It sounds like a repository might be too complex for me right now!

Comment: Lol it isn't, it's a simple concept. You just need to understand the nuances: repository abstracts everything storage and serves as a boundary keeper while a DAO is an object which helps you to work easier with the db (think PDO). For simple apps there is practically no difference between them. It requires something more complex to really see the differences. Let's say that a Repo is domain/business centric while a DAO is db centric.

Comment: Ok Mike, I have been thinking, and trying to wrap my mind around this. It's not easy to understand. Is there a way that you can explain this further maybe by example "repository abstracts everything storage and serves as a boundary keeper while a DAO is an object which helps you to work easier with the db (think PDO)." And to clarify when you say ("A DAO is ---think PDO)? I really do want to understand this!

Comment: I've wrote yesterday on my blog about this http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/11/01/Repository-vs-DAO.aspx. About PDO (PHP Data Object) as an object used to simplify db access, in my book it's a DAO, albeit a lower level DAO (it hides some things but not enough). A 'higher level' DAO hides even the fact it executes queries.